# Switch in Javascript [spits same value]

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Aside the hate that's gonna spill on me for changing DOM elements in JS I feel like I've been cheated on by switch.

Never have I had a problem with it but this time it spits out in console easy everytime I call the function.

```
var opt = 0;

var arr = ['easy','medium','high'];

function difficulity(){
switch(opt){
case 0:
case 1:
  console.log(arr[opt]);
  document.getElementById("diffArr").innerHTML = arr[opt];
  opt = opt++;
  break;
case 2:
  console.log(arr[opt]);
  document.getElementById("diffArr").innerHTML = arr[opt];
  opt = 0;
  break;
} 
};
```

As you may see I want the code to change the text inside element and the console always say it's "easy" eventhough the opt variable should change everytime the function is being called.

Thank you for the help in advance, let me know if I messed up something.

Comment: `opt++` returns the value of `opt` before it increments it.  Change `opt = opt++;` to simply `opt++;`

Comment: Incidentally, you don't need the switch statement to get the same functionality.  Remove it and increment `opt` with `opt = ++opt % arr.length;` (increments it but also sets it to 0 when it reaches the length of the array)

Comment: … the non-confusing way to write that being `opt = (opt + 1) % arr.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`opt = opt++;` wont work

either you use

```
opt = opt + 1;
```

or

```
opt++;
```

Hope this helps

```js
var opt = 0;

var arr = ['easy','medium','high'];

function difficulity(){
switch(opt){
case 0:
case 1:
  console.log(arr[opt]);
  document.getElementById("diffArr").innerHTML = arr[opt];
  opt++;
  break;
case 2:
  console.log(arr[opt]);
  document.getElementById("diffArr").innerHTML = arr[opt];
  opt = 0;
  break;
} 
};
```

```html
<button onclick="difficulity()">Call function</button>
<p id="diffArr"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you! 
This one is the most useful since I really wanted to use the switch. 

All the other responses were doing their job, I feel bad for not noticing this little incrementation problem.

Comment: Glad it helped! Code On

Comment: It's 12 PM in Poland. Time to go to sleep actually :') 
Tommorow I'll be back with more questions! Take care.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
opt = opt++;
```

This increments `opt` by one (on the right) and then assigns the *initial* value of `opt` to `opt` (on the left). That's what postincrement does:

> If used postfix, with operator after operand (for example, x++), then it returns the value before incrementing.

When incrementing with `++` or decrementing with `--`, you don't need to (and shouldn't) *assign* the result to the same variable - just use the `++` alone. For example:

```
case 1:
  console.log(arr[opt]);
  document.getElementById("diffArr").innerHTML = arr[opt];
  opt++;
  break;
```

```js
var opt = 0;

var arr = ['easy', 'medium', 'high'];

function difficulity() {
  switch (opt) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
      console.log(arr[opt]);
      document.getElementById("diffArr").innerHTML = arr[opt];
      opt++;
      break;
    case 2:
      console.log(arr[opt]);
      document.getElementById("diffArr").innerHTML = arr[opt];
      opt = 0;
      break;
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="diffArr"></div>
<div onclick="difficulity()">click</div>
```

But `switch` is a bit verbose and error-prone - you might consider just using array lookup instead:

```js
var opt = 0;
var arr = ['easy', 'medium', 'high'];
const diffArr = document.getElementById("diffArr");
function difficulity() {
  diffArr.textContent = arr[opt++ % arr.length];
}
```

```html
<div onclick="difficulity()">click</div>
<div id="diffArr"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I've been looking for. 
Dumb me! :)

Answer (score 0):

As explained already, `opt = opt++` basically sets it to it's current value.  `opt++` would do what you want.

However, I'd recommend getting rid of the switch statement as you can achieve the exact same result with this...

```js
var opt = 0;

var arr = ['easy','medium','high'];

function difficulty(){
    console.log(arr[opt]);
    document.getElementById("diffArr").innerHTML = arr[opt];
    opt = ++opt % arr.length;
}

// just run it 10 times to see the result.
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  difficulty();
}
```

```html
<div id="diffArr"></div>
```

In short, what that does is set opt to opt + 1 with this..

```
opt = ++opt
```

and then uses the modulus operator which returns the remainder after dividing your number by another number, in this case the length of the array.

```
opt = ++opt % arr.length;
```

This means that you can add things to the array, or remove them, and the code will still function as desired, without having to modify anything else.